# Running nightmare node js app in iisnode

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, nightmare

We have created a node js app with hapi node js and included some functionality web scraping functionality using nighmare node js.

There were few API's exposed using hapi and everything works fine with running the app in command line like "node app.js".

But when the app is hosted in IIS using iisnode, then it hangs. Not sure what is the problem...

So, my question is whether nightmare node js would work in iis node??

Please help in this regard.

Comment: Any log messages?

Comment: No errors found. After hosting in iis node and calling the api will hang forever. So, the basic doubt I'm having is whether nightmare nodejs apps would run in iis node? Please help.

Comment: Tough subject to google. Most of the searches return people saying that using IIS is a nightmare...

Comment: Yeah. Agreed, never I have come across a solution where nightmare node js app is hosted in iis node.

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try running with `DEBUG=nightmare*,electron*` set and see if that yields helpful output.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I have successfully done this using IIS ARR.

No iisnode is required. You basically run your node app as lets say localhost:3000 and run ISS with ARR (Application Request Routing). You create servers on IIS ARR that reverse proxy to localhost:3000. So you'd end up with something like

example.com <-ARR-> localhost:3000

Make sure localhost:3000 is not publicly available.